# MySql command to see all the ip that ever connected to the MySql server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu

is there a way to see all the ip's that ever connected to my MySql server? Thanks.

Ps: I use a ubuntu 16 server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve client ip address in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263453/retrieve-client-ip-address-in-mysql)

Comment: No MySQL or Linux doesn't have defualt commands for that.. You need to create a logging chain for iptables or you need to monitor information_schema.processlist and save those ip's into a table with a php cronjob or a MySQL event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL how to log thread connections (I need user and ip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385776/mysql-how-to-log-thread-connections-i-need-user-and-ip)

Comment: Please visit following link may be it helps you. https://www.mkyong.com/linux/list-all-ip-addresses-connected-to-your-server/